# A Polynomial which Factors, but has no Roots?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am told to give an example of a polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients which factors (poly $mod$ $n$),
but which has no roots, i.e., for which there are no integers $x$ such that $f(x) ≡ 0$ ($mod$ $n$).

I am also given a hint: Your solution should give a specific integer $n$, and give all of the coefficients of
$f(x)$. It should show that $f(x)$ really does factor, and it should prove that $f(x)$ has no
roots.

Comment: Take your favorite irreducible polynomial of degree $> 1$ (for some specific $n$, e.g., $n = 2$) and square that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^4+1=(x^2+2)(x^2+3)$ mod 5 is such a polynomial

Comment: Can you show how you got that solution?

Comment: By using quadratic residues. Do you know this concept ?

Comment: I am not familiar with that concept.

Comment: Less complicated response: JeanMarie simply took the product of two polynomials with no roots.

Comment: @Hurkyl, I appreciate your comment that suffices for Crazed for the moment. Nevertheless, it is interesting to know that such a "theory" exists... because it permits to ensure that there are solutions for congruence modulo any prime.

Comment: In my solution $x^4+1$ has no roots because, by exhaustion of the 5 cases : $0^1+1=1$ is not 0 mod 5, $1^1+1=2$ is not 0 mod 5, $2^1+1=3$ is not 0 mod 5, ...

Comment: Ah! That's what I wasn't getting. Thank you!

Comment: @Crazed Hurkyl correctly explained the idea behind JeanMarie's answer: multiply any two (nonlinear) polynomials each with no roots, and the result will be a polynomial that has no roots but factors. Quadratic residues provide for a special case of simple quadratic polynomials with no roots.

Answer (score 2):

Over $\mathbf F_p$, there are irreducible polynomials of every degree, which have no  root if their degree is $>1$. Take  the product of any finite number of  such irreducible polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4+4 = (x^4+4x^2+4)-(4x^2) = (x^2+2)^2 - (2x)^2 = (x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2) $$
and $x^2\pm 2x+2 = (x\pm 1)^2+1$ has a negative discriminant, but completely splits over any $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ (granting that $-1$ is a quadratic residue).